# How to limit postgresql to use only n CPU cores?

Tags: postgresql

How do we can limit the postgresql to use only n CPU cores and leave the rest for other processes? For example I have 16 cores and I want to dedicate 8 cores to postgresql and reserve the rest 8 cores for other services.

Comment: You might want to try [pg_cgroups](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/pg_cgroups-linux-control-groups-in-postgresql/)

Comment: Might be better asked on sister site, http://DBA.StackExchange.com/. Not really a programming problem.

Comment: @BasilBourque, you are right but there are many other questions on stackoverflow about postgres and I thought it is ok to ask the question here.

Comment: Yes, there is some overlap between http://DBA.StackExchange.com and http://www.StackOverflow.com… when some programming is involved. But there is *no programming issue involved* at all in your Question. Administering servers is off-topic here, and belong on sister site https://serverfault.com instead. Administering networks is off-topic here, and belong on sister site https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com. Administering databases is off-topic here, and belongs on https://dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible to confine the PostgreSQL server to a subset of available CPU cores, as there is no configuration or mechanism to achieve it.  However, it is possible to leverage NUMA to [start Postgres with a limited number of CPU cores available](https://richyen.com/postgres/2016/01/14/numa_spinlocks_issue.html).

In short, if your operating system allows for it, you can do something like:

```
numactl --hardware
NUMA0_CPUS=”0-7”
export CPUSET_HOME=$(mount | grep cpuset)
sudo mkdir $CPUSET_HOME/postgres
sudo /bin/bash -c "echo $NUMA0_CPUS >$CPUSET_HOME/postgres/cpus"
sudo /bin/bash -c "echo '0' >$CPUSET_HOME/postgres/mems"
sudo chown postgres $CPUSET_HOME/postgres/tasks
sudo su - $PGSERVERUSER
export CPUSET_HOME="<path where cpusets are mounted>"
echo $$ >$CPUSET_HOME/postgres/tasks
pg_ctl start <usual start parameters>
```

Comment: thanks for your response but I think the pg_cgroups is more straightforward and I probably follow that path.